# Card IO - Hide Manual Entry

Tags: cordova-plugins, card.io

I am using card.io through cordova. Is there a way to hide the manual entry option? We already have our own method of manual entry built in so it would be redundant to have in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this line](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap/blob/master/src/ios/CardIOCordovaPlugin.m#L51) from the cordova plugin help?

Answer (score 4):

For Native app, there is "disableManualEntryButtons" option, it helps to hide